# How do I add a once only function to this pop up code?

Tags: javascript, popup

I asked this question yesterday, but I didn't use enough detail. I have this pop up code but I'm having trouble figuring out how to modify it for a once only action.

```js
$(function(){
  var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
  overlay.show();
  overlay.appendTo(document.body);
  $('.popup').show();
  $('.close').click(function(){
  $('.popup').hide();
  overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
  return false;
});

$('.x').click(function(){
  $('.popup').hide();
  overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
  return false;
});
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity:0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}
.cnt223 a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.popup{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
}
.cnt223{
  min-width: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 103;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
}
.cnt223 p{
  clear: both;
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.cnt223 p a{
  color: #d91900;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.cnt223 .x{
  float: right;
  height: 35px;
  left: 22px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  width: 34px;
}
.cnt223 .x:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='popup'>
  <div class='cnt223'>
    <h1>Important Notice</h1>
    <p>
    We were affected by the fire next door and will remain closed until further notice.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href='' class='close'>Close</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Code to produce a Javascript pop up on page load can be found here](https://codepen.io/pedrobenoit91/pen/aJGzYg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not very good at this. How would I make this only appear once on page load?

Comment: What do you mean by: *modify it for a once only action.*

Comment: I mean. How do I make it so that it on;y appears once when a page loads for an individual. And then never again? It's a question that's been bugging me. I tried to fix it myself to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand what you mean by have the modal appear only once on page load. Is it that you want the modal to appear only on the first ever page load and not appear in any subsequent page reload? If so, then you can achieve this by using `localStorage` as follows

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        if (!localStorage['show-popup']) {
            var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
            overlay.show();
            overlay.appendTo(document.body);

            $('.popup').show();
            $('.close').click(function () {
                $('.popup').hide();
                overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
                return false;
            });

            $('.x').click(function () {
                $('.popup').hide();
                overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
                return false;
            });
            localStorage['show-popup'] = disable
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i need. I tried implementing it, but for some reason it isn't accessing local storage.